# An ancient C++ compiler and IDE for DOS

Tags: c++, ide, dos, legacy

Around 2006-7 when I was quite young, I had a Windows XP machine with a legacy C++ compiler and IDE installed. I am now trying to remember what the product's name was.

All I remember is that the editor opened in text mode and was obviously designed for DOS. The name "PGCPP" rings a bell, but all some googling found was PGI Compilers & Tools, who specialise in compilers for parallel computing. I downloaded an old release of theirs from 2000, and it contains their proprietary compiler alongside a Cygwin environment, including Vim and Emacs. This is clearly not the IDE I remember.

I remember downloading it for free, legally. It may have been a trial version, I suppose, but I do not remember.

Does anyone with C++ experience spanning around 15-20 years have any idea what product I used back then?

---

**EDIT**: The software was called [DJGPP](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/) and it seems to still be maintained.

Comment: [Turbo C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That is possible. I definitely didn't pay for this IDE though, that's for sure - and I didn't know how to pirate things at that age!

Comment: Turbo C++ had a freeware version according to wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I asked on BetaArchive](http://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=35413&p=407613) and somebody, somehow, had used that software before!

The software I remember is called [DJGPP](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/). It is a suite of GNU programs, including GCC, ported to DOS.